# 'Me' vs 'my' [pronunciation] in British English

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, dialect, vowels

I noticed that British people sometimes use **me** instead of **my**. For example, Liam Gallagher does it quite often.
Example:

> *The wind was strong I have nearly lost me pants*

What is a story behind this alteration? Is it appropriate in formal language? Do people really speak like that? Or is this a dialect rather than a widely spread manner?

Comment: It's one of the main features of Northern accents.

Comment: @Lambie -  The sentence itself is not idiomatic by a long stretch, only the `mi` for `my`. More idiomatic would be 'The wind was so strong I nearly lost `mi` pants." Though if your accent would use `mi` like that, it would also transform `I` into `à` like in `lad`

Comment: @gonefishin'again. or indeed almost pronounce _I_ as _uh_ especially when talking fast.

Comment: @mdewey - In Northern BrE? Interesting. What town, if you're a native? It's not one I'd think would shift to a schwa [though many others do in N.BrE ;)

Comment: @gonefishin'again. no quite generally. I think the use of me for my is quite widespread in fast informal speech in BrE.

Comment: There is no "generally" in BrE, there is a line drawn across the country - Liverpool to the Wash, very roughly - one side speaks one way, the other side another.

Comment: @mdewey - btw, I was talking about your schwa for `I` not `mi` for `my`.

Comment: @gone fishin' again: Plus lots of regional dialects/accents.  Perhaps less so today than in the past, given electronic media, but still lots of differences perceptible even to a casual visitor: https://englishlive.ef.com/blog/english-in-the-real-world/rough-guide-british-dialects/

Comment: @jamesqf - yup, I'm a N.BrE native, now living in London, hence my questioning the schwa for I earlier.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is not a substitution of *me* for *my* but a common dialectal pronunciation of *my* (Northern England and some Australian accents).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language_in_Northern_England), other areas of the North have regularised the pronouns in the opposite direction, with *meself used instead of myself*.

Moreover, the vowel in 'me' (the one you're referring to) is shorter ([**mi**]) than that of the regular 'me' ([**mi:**]) and this pronuncation of 'my' is usually used where 'my' is unstressed.

The pronunciation of emphatic/stressed 'my' was [[**mi:**] in Middle English](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/mi#Middle_English) (before the Great Vowel Shift) and its [unstressed/unemphatic form was [mi]](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/mi#Middle_English).

The [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) was a vowel change (1400-1700) that shifted almost all the long vowels to diphthongs but it did not affect short vowels. So the pronunciation of emphatic 'my' shifted to [aɪ]* but the short vowel in 'my' [mi] in its unemphatic form remained unaffected in some accents (Northern British, Irish, some Australian accents etc).

<sub>*GVS shifted [iː] to [aɪ]. For example, the pronunciation of 'bite' was /bi:t/ before the GVS.</sub>

Comment: It is important to stress that this is _not_ a substitution of "me" for "my" as the question asserts.  It is a pronunciation of "my", and can also be observed for many other words ending in "-y", including the word "many" in this very sentence.

Comment: @JdeBP I didn't understand the example about "many". Is "many" ever pronounced "man-eye"?

Comment: @PedroA No, and that, I believe, is the point.

Comment: @PedroA It's men-ee and the ee is the same sound in "me", but it's spelt with a "y"

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ah, I get it now, thanks

Comment: So is this related to the phenomenon of pronouncing the the "y" in "my" as a schwa?

Comment: No. 'My' in its weak form is often pronounced [mə] (in fast speech) in many accents, not just Northern British accents.

Comment: "the pronunciation of emphatic/stressed 'my' was [mi:] in Middle English (before the Great Vowel Shift) and it's unstressed/unemphatic form was [mi]": was that also true in the north?  Did the vowel shift introduce a regional variation in pronunciation that didn't exist before?  If so, why did it affect this word and not (for example) "dry"?  (Or did it?)  Also, this being an English language site, I would change *it's* to *its,* but I don't have sufficient reputation to do it */maɪˈsɛlf/.*  Also, wouldn't *beet* have been pronounced /be:t/, so still differently from *bite*?

Comment: @phoog, You're absolutely right. **Re** "was that also true in the north? Did the vowel shift introduce a regional variation in pronunciation that didn't exist before?": As far as I know, it was also true in the North and it introduced regional variations in pronunciation. There are lots of remnants of Middle/Old English in the North  For example, people in the North pronounce 'but' with [ʊ] rather than [ʌ]. You also hear 'house' being pronounced with [u:] (hoose) in the North. It's because GVS didn't affect some words in the North. I don't know why.

Comment: **Re** "why did it affect this word and not (for example) "dry"? (Or did it?)": Because words like *me, myself, the, at, an, them* etc (I'm not a grammarian so I don't know the umbrella term for these words, sorry) are often reduced and pronounced in their weak forms. For example, you might've noticed that *them* is reduced to *em* in fast speech. However, you cannot reduce the words that have meaning on their own like 'dry' so it does not have a weak form.

Comment: **Re** "Also, this being an English language site, I would change it's to its": Ah.... it's my annoying but useful 'autocorrect' feature. I was typing on phone so the autocorrect turned *its* into *it's*.

Comment: **Re** "Also, wouldn't beet have been pronounced /be:t/, so still differently from bite?": Yes, that's my bad. I was talking about the pronunciation of 'beet' in Modern English. I should've written /bi:t/ instead.

Answer (score 5):

It is very common to avoid pronouncing the long "ai" sound in "my" when speaking fast and/or informally.

Some people use a schwa as in "I've lost mə keys."

In Britain a short "i" sound is common, e.g. "I've lost mi keys."

My guess is that Gallagher said "...lost mi pants" rather than "lost me (mee) pants."

Comment: I have to note that this was not the Gallagher‘s quote. It was just a sentence I have made up. I have heard him say **me** in some interview. And yes, it sounded more like **mi**.